# Is it a good practice to choose a model based on POST-ed model class name?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Suppose we have models `A`, and `B` and we need to choose which one of them to instantiate **based on the information posted from the view**.

Would it be a good practice to do something like this:

```
// ...
$this->validate($request, [
    'model.class_name' => 'in:A,B' // restrict users to only pass either 'A' or 'B' as class_name
])

$data       = $request()->get('model'); // <-- contains: $data['id'] and $data['class_name']

$id         = $data['id'];
$class_name = $data['class_name'];

$$class_name::find($id); // <-- notice, that we are using POST-ed 'class_name' to determine which model we want to use!
// ...
```

Or can this approach introduce some problems in the future?

Comment: It's very bad to use any type of user input without validating it. What happens if someone sends in a class name that should't be accessible? You should have a controller that checks the request, validates it and chooses the appropriate model to use.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, naturally. Just forgot to include validations into the snippet. Thanks for pointing that out. Other than validating the `class_name`, can there be any other issues?

Comment: I wouldn't put the class name in my view, i would put it in my controller and just let the view send something like 1, 2, 3 etc... then you can use the same view in different controllers that translates them differently, and you only need to change the controller if you need to swap out a model name. And you don't expose your class names to the users.... but this is just my opinion...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for the insight, however I'm asking more about whether it's a good practice to use the technique itself, rather than the specifics of the implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer is **No**.

**Reason:**

> **What if your model `A`   has different functionality than `B` ?**

In this case you need to add extra checks which function need to call if `A` is given and what if `B` and so on.Also if you think that you have same set of functionality you should use [Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx), For laravel see [this](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/) ,this will  help you to make your system more scalable, flexible and maintainable.

**Its good to know what complete requirement and according to that do code.**

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good point. What about binding `A` and `B` with the same contract? That way, the api problem will be solved.

Comment: Repository Pattern its actually based on  contract, So what you are thinking is already proposed with this pattern.